# C# simple "for" and "int" issue

Tags: c#, int, increment, decrement, console.writeline

Im trying to learn C# from scratch and I have issue with one simple task. I cant understand why this is Not working,can you please explain me :

```
     namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class intro
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i;
            int j;
            for (i = 1; j=-1; i <= 100 && j >= -100; i += 2, j -=2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i+j);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:  I missed why is NOT working, sorry for that. Semicolon instead of colon was the problem... Stupid question but thank you for patience.

Comment: Simple. You're looping until `i <= 100 && j >= -100`. Each loop, `i` has 2 added to it.. `j` has 2 removed. You should review basic `for..` loops if you don't understand this.

Comment: The code actually doesn't compile. Should be "for(i=1, j=-1" ...comma instead of semicolon.

Comment: This code does not compile (`for(;;;)` ).

Comment: This site is better for explaining why code is _not_ working. What is your actual question here?

Comment: Why this code _is_ working, or why this code _isn't_ working?

Comment: Leaving out a __not__ is a big typo in a question... Also, always provide the full error messages.

Comment: Your `for` is doing -1+1 = 0 then +3-3=0 then +5-5=0 then ... then +n-n=0

Comment: Yes, I just realized this... Thinking is really good thing if you actually can do it... It was stupid question but thank you for patience and answers !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a very common mistake, you placed `;' in the place ',';

```
for (i = 1, j=-1; i <= 100....
```

I don't know what you want to do with the code but it produce only '0' but the code is working as it should.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by:

> I cant understand why this is working

It is working because it is a valid code.Except this comma should be semicolon:

```
i = 1; <-- wrong
i = 1, <-- correct
```

You are constructing a for loop.You define two variable,`i` and `j` then,you starting `i` from `1` and j form `-1`. Then you specify the loop condition. `i <= 100 && j >= -100`.With this condition you are saying the loop should execute as long as `i <= 100` AND `j >= -100` And last statement you specifying the expression which will be executed in every step.That's it.

Answer (score 0):

`for` loop needs to have a structure of

```
for (initializer; condition; iterator)
    body
```

Please refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx), these are the most basics of every programming language.